# Cortar string por um caractere específico e com índice no BigQuery

Tags: sql, string, bigquery

Tenho alguns dados que preciso fazer um corte apartir da segunda ocorrência do pipe "|", uso Substring_Index no MySQL, porém no BigQuery não consegui achar uma solução que contempla o índice da ocorrência.

**O que eu tenho:**

> 2463|134|87 
> 457|4|0 
> 3|113544|9887132

**O retorno que preciso:**

> 2463|134
> 457|4
> 3|113544

**O que Tentei:**

> `SELECT STRPOS ('3|113544|9887132','|') AS Exemplo1`
> `SELECT SPLIT('3|113544|9887132','|') [offset(2)] AS Exemplo2`

Answer (score -1):

Consegui essa solução que me ajudou a chegar no resultado.

```
select concat(split('444|555|5','|') [offset(0)],"|",split('444|555|5','|') [offset(1)])
```

Resultado:

```
444|555
```